# awk if-else and variable reassignment

Tags: if-statement, awk, syntax

I have a text file consisting of xyz coordinates, each defining a particular depth contour of a slope.
All of these lines are stored in one file, with each contour separated by ">"

The file looks like:

```
 >
 x1  y1  z1
 x2  y2  z2
 >
 x3  y3  z3
     ...
```

The file is huge and unwieldy and I want to print out the 7th point along each contour and pipe it into a tab delimited new file.

My code looks like this:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' -v count=1 '{if ($1 == ">") {count/=count}; else if (count%7 == 0) {{count+=1} print $0}; else {count+=1}}' infile > outfile
```

I keep getting an error message that says

```
    awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
    {if ($1 == ">") {count/=count}; >>>  else <<<  if (count%7 == 0) {{count+=1}; print $0}; else {count+=1}}
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
```

I've spent a while checking my syntax and bracketing and it seems ok, I just might be missing something with the variable reassignment?

Comment: Remove the `; ` between the `}` and `else`, ie. `if(1) something(); else` but `if(1) { some(); thing() } else` so you could basically: `if ($1 == ">") count/=count; else ` or `if ($1 == ">") {count/=count} else `

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is very close; just a bit off. Looks like there may be some confusion between the curly braces `{ }` and the normal parentheses. As you play around more with awk the difference should become much clearer.

Before I get to your particular syntax issue, note that a simpler approach can solve the same problem:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '$1 == ">" { count = 1; next } !(count++ % 7)' file
```

A multiline version your corrected code would be:

```
{
  if ($1 == ">") {
    count = 1
  }
  else
    if (count % 7 == 0) {
      count += 1
      print $0
    }
    else
      count += 1
}
```

As long as a statement is on its own line, you don't need a semicolon. But note that to make it a one-liner, you will need one as shown:

```
{ if ($1 == ">") { count = 1  } else if (count % 7 == 0) { count += 1; print $0 } else count += 1 }
```